# WPF DisplayMemberPath not Updating when SelectedItem is removed

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox

I have simplified this problem down as much as I can. Basically I am overriding the "null" value of a combobox. So that if the item selected is deleted, it reverts back to "(null)". Unfortunately the behaviour of this is wrong, I hit delete, the ObservableCollection item is removed, thus the property binding is updated and it returns the "(null)" item as expected. But the combobox appearance shows blank. Yet the value its bound to is correct... this problem can be reproduced with the code below.

To reproduce this problem you select an item, and hit remove. Notice at this point the following line is called (when you remove the selected item). So its a good place to breakpoint.

```
                if (m_Selected == null)
            {
                return Items[0]; //items 0 is ItemNull
            }
```

Also notice that I have attmpted to fix it by Forcing a property update on the DisplayMemberPath. This did not work.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WPFCodeDump.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"></ComboBox>
        <Button  Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">Remove Selected</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WPFCodeDump
{
    public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }

    //Item class
    public class Item : ViewModelBase
    {
        public Item(string name)
        {
            m_Name = name;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return m_Name; }
        }
        private string m_Name;

        public void ForcePropertyUpdate()
        {
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    //Item class
    public class ItemNull : Item
    {
        public ItemNull()
            : base("(null)")
        {
        }
    }

    class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            m_Items.Add(new ItemNull());
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                m_Items.Add(new Item("TestItem" + i));
            }
            Selected = null;
        }

        //Remove selected command
        public void RemoveSelected()
        {
            Items.Remove(Selected);
        }

        //The item list
        private ObservableCollection<Item> m_Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
        {
            get { return m_Items; }
        }

        //Selected item
        private Item m_Selected;
        public Item Selected
        {
            get
            {
                if (m_Selected == null)
                {
                    return Items[0]; //items 0 is ItemNull
                }
                return m_Selected;
            }
            set
            {
                m_Selected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                if(m_Selected!=null) m_Selected.ForcePropertyUpdate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WPFCodeDump
{


    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
        }

        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((MainWindowViewModel) DataContext).RemoveSelected();
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result after pressing remove]

Comment: *return Items[0]*... return from what? What's that supposed to do? Surely you just need `Selected = Items[0]` (assuming that `Items[0]` is an actual item from the data bound collection).

Comment: Have you tried to set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` at your SelectedItem-Binding?

Comment: It returns ItemNull() which is an instance inside of m_Items

Comment: @Tomtom tried that, same problem. Isnt it propertychanged by default anyway?

Comment: @Sheridan sorry this doesn't work either. Does it work for you?

Comment: @Sheridan The value of the `Selected` property is the instance of `ItemNull` which is added in the first line of the VM's constructor. Inspecting the program in Snoop confirms that the `SelectedItem` is returning the correct object instance however the displayed text is still blank instead of the string `"(null)"` as it should be.

Comment: @Sean I never thought of trying Snoop. Thanks! At least we can confirm that the problem is more deep-seeded. If the value in snoop is what we expected it to be yet the value displayed on the combobox is blank. Something totally strange is happening.....

Comment: @TheodosiusVonRichthofen all the code to compile the project is above?

Comment: it doesn't compile.  where is ButtonBase_OnClick method

Comment: what is the error? I cant post missing code unless you tell me whats missing.

Comment: ButtonBase_OnClick method there is no definition for

Comment: Updated it - sorry I originally used an ICommand but removed that for simplicity. Its just a call to the view model to remove the item.

Comment: See the above code for the MainWindow.xaml.cs - this attaches the ViewModel.

Comment: I am not seeing where a RemoveSelected is going to cause a NotifyPropertyChanged on Selected?  In debug the get is called and returns Items[0]?

Comment: @Blam the binding engine will cause this to happen when the item is removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A nice binding issue you found there. But as always, it's our fault, not theirs :)

The issue(s) is(are), using `DisplayMemberPath` with `SelectedItem`.
The `DisplayMemberPath` doesn't give a f*** about the changed `SelectedItem`.

What you have to do, to resolve this issue, are two things:

First, in the `RemoveSelected` method, set the `Selected` property to null (to force an update on the binding):

```
public void RemoveSelected()
{
    Items.Remove(Selected);
    Selected = null;
}
```

Then, in the XAML-definition, change the bound property:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

Binding the `SelectedValue` property will correctly update the displayed text in the `ComboBox`.

Comment: Wow this works. Is there a way to get around "Selected = null"? The at the point in the code I dont unfortunately know about Selected (as I do in my example).

I could get around this however by subscribing to the ItemsSource OnCollectionChanged event....

Comment: Sorry to be more clear. My selected item doesn't know about the collection its bound to.

Comment: Guess then you got to do it at a location which knows about both...?

Comment: Yeah, the only way. Ill work around it. Thank you VERY MUCH one thousand upvotes for reading the question before giving me a clear concise answer!!!

Comment: interesting...so what is supposed to happen when the user select (null) and then the remove button?  it goes to the next item?  huh?  and if the user keeps clicking remove it will eventually just blow up, since there is no Items[0]?  this doesn't seem like a very good design.  hopefully you're leaving out the reasons behind this

Comment: @Asheh No problem. Just remember that the `DisplayMemberPath` is your friend when working with `SelectedValue`. When working with `SelectedItem`, `ItemTemplate` is your friend :)

Comment: @TheodosiusVonRichthofen Yes. It gonna blow somewhen. OP needs to add logic that prevents deleting the `NullItem`.

Comment: ^ Yeah. Its just minimal code to show you guys the issue!

Comment: Personally I'm not a big fan of using `SelectedValue` without also using `SelectedValuePath`... to me it makes the code look like something is wrong to me. I would rather have the `.RemoveSelected()` method use a temp value and set the selected item to `null` before removing the previously selected item. For example, `var tmp = Selected; Selected = null; Items.Remove(x);` also results in the correct behavior without needing to change `SelectedItem`  (which reads correctly to me) to `SelectedValue` (which seems incorrect to me since `SelectedValuePath` isn't set)

Comment: I agree with Rachel here, and I tend to use SelectedItem.  another alternative would be                     //Remove selected command
        public void RemoveSelected()
        {
            if (Selected != Items[0])
            {
                int idx = Items.IndexOf(Selected);
                Selected = null;
                Items.RemoveAt(idx);
            }
        }